# Sorting column must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using a [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) database in my `phoenix` application. I have a table of `buses`, each of which is associated with one or more `stops` and `routes`. I'm trying to make a searchable list of all stops, but I don't want to re-write my searching and filtering functions (see `list_filtered_buses`).

So, in `sort_bus_list`, I'm trying to return a sorted list of all stops.
**My issue with the current implementation is that I get back duplicates when I render the list in my template since each bus is being returned with all its stops.** I've tried two different approaches, one returning duplicates, and one preventing sorting due to an error.

Here is relevant code in sort_bus_list in `buses.ex`:

```
  # V1 - sortable, but returns duplicates
  list
    |> order_by([b, s, r], {^attrs.sort_dir, field(s, ^attrs.sort_attr)})
    |> group_by([b, s, r], [s.id, b.id])

  # V2 - doesn't return duplicates, but isn't returns error:
  # ERROR 42803 (grouping_error): column "b1.stop_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
    list
    |> order_by([b, s, r], {^attrs.sort_dir, field(s, ^attrs.sort_attr)})
    |> group_by([b, s, r], b.id)
```

Here's pseudo-code of my template:

```
for bus in Buses
    for stop in bus
        display stop
    end
end
```

More `buses.ex` code for context:

```
 def list_filtered_buses(params) do
  search_term = params["filter"]["query"]

  from(t in Bus, join: a in assoc(t, :stops), join: c in assoc(t, :routes))
  |> search(search_term)
  |> list_buses_by_active(params)
  |> list_buses_by_type(params)
  |> sort_buses_list(params)
  |> preload([:stops, :routes])
 end


def sort_bus_list(list, params) do
  attrs = process_sorting_metrics(params)

  case params["filter"]["sort_attr"] do
    a when a == "stop_name" or a == "stop_id" ->

  #V2 - sortable, but returns duplcate
  list
    |> order_by([b, s, r], {^attrs.sort_dir, field(s, ^attrs.sort_attr)})
    |> group_by([b, s, r], [s.id, b.id])

  "route_name" ->
    list
    |> order_by([b, s, r], {^attrs.sort_dir, field(r, ^attrs.sort_attr)})
    |> group_by([b, s, r], [b.id, r.id])

  _ ->
    list
    |> order_by([b, s, r], {^attrs.sort_dir, field(b, ^attrs.sort_attr)})
    |> group_by([b, s, r], b.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: I am surely missing something, but the problem as it is stated has an obvious solution `from(s in Stop)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think the problem lies with the way you're structuring your query in general. [See this](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/). If that doesn't help, try [rephrasing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), focusing on the core problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, you're trying to render only `Stop`. In the `list_filtered_buses` function, you're running a query on `Bus` table. Then, further you're trying to sort and group the data. The #V1 function is doing a group on `Bus.id` and `Stop.id` so you get duplicate `Stop`s in case different `Bus`es have same `Stop`s. The #V2 function however returns error because you're doing a `select` query on `Bus` and you're doing `group` only on `Bus`.id and trying to render attributes from `Stop`.

As @AlekseiMatiushkin suggested, in order to render only distinct `Stop`s, you need to do a `from(s in Stop)`.